# why I could use first() method when my resultset type is forward only?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using the default `ResultSet` when I do a JDBC call. I'm surprised that after using `next()` to iterate the `ResultSet`, I could call `first()` to back to the first row. This is not meant by using forward only `ResultSet`?

My code is quite simple:

```
  Statement st = conn.createStatement();
  rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
        if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
        String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
        System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + " : " + columnValue);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
rs.first();
```

I am using 8.0.11 version of mysql connector

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where are you declaring the result set as `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`? Also, are you sure no exceptions are being thrown? Please share a minimal but _complete_ example so that others can reproduce your scenario.

Comment: first() will throw SQLException - "if result set is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY"

Comment: Have you verified that the result set type is actually `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`? JDBC drivers are allowed to upgrade or downgrade result set types if they think that is better

Comment: @MickMnemonic The JDBC API documentation for [`Connection.createStatement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement()) explicitly says _"Result sets created using the returned `Statement` object will by default be type `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`"_

Comment: I verified it is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour for MySQL Connector/J is to load the entire contents of the `ResultSet` into memory as soon as `.executeQuery` is called. So, even though our `ResultSet` is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` the MySQL JDBC developers apparently decided to be "nice" and allow us to use `.first`, `.absolute`, etc. in that case (because the entire `ResultSet` is in memory and readily available), even though the JDBC spec says

> For a `ResultSet` object that is of type `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, the only valid cursor
>   movement method is `next`. All other cursor movement methods throw an
>   `SQLException`.

Note, however, that if the entire `ResultSet` is not guaranteed to be in memory, e.g., if we use `st.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` to "stream" the `ResultSet` as we scroll through it, then MySQL Connector/J won't let us use anything but `.next` or we'll get

```
com.mysql.jdbc.OperationNotSupportedException: Operation not supported for streaming result sets
```

Comment: If MySQL had followed the JDBC spec, they should either disallow it, or upgrade the result set type to a scrollable result set.